# How can I trim post with special characters in post method?

Tags: php, arrays, post, trim

How can I trim post with special characters in post method?

My code is :

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    session_start();
    set_time_limit(0);

    if (isset($_GET['title'])){
    $title = $_GET['title'];
    } elseif (isset($_POST['title'])){
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    } else {
    print(json_encode(array("status" => 0)));
    exit();
    }

    if (!trim($title)){
    print(json_encode(array("status" => 0)));
    exit();
    }

    extract($_POST);
    ?>
```

For example Title in post request, will be like this `myscript.php?title=Pain & Gain`

when I output with `echo $title;`

I got just this `Pain`

There is no `& Gain`

Comment: you have encode your url before creating it with the help of `encodeURIComponent` or `urlencode()`. see docs

Answer (score 0):

use function `url_encode`

```
myscript.php?title=<?php echo url_encode("Pain & Gain")?>
```

and decode it when you get from request

```
$title = url_decode($_GET['title']);
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if your form method is post then the issue will not be there. If there is get method u will have this issue I think. Try the following -

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="a" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['a']) && !empty($_GET['a'])){
  echo urldecode($_GET['a']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your time, i fixed problem by searching on google whole day to solve this issue...  Basic what i did is > $title = urldecode(str_replace('title=', '', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])); <